# JavaFX - How do you open and display an image in a pane?

Tags: java, image, model-view-controller, javafx

I am trying to create an application that will allow users to open an image file and display it in a pane. I have chosen JavaFX to create the GUI but this has presented some difficultly with the code below:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable 
{

  ...

  public void openFile()
  { 
    fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);

    if (file != null)
    {
      // display the image in the pane
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

Basically, I need my `Controller` class to update the `pane` in my view which is defined in the .fxml file as below:

```
<Pane maxHeight="1.8" style="-fx-border-color: #000000;" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
```

As it is I can not find a way to do so because I cannot reference the `pane`.

Comment: Can you show where you defined `panel`? Did you inject it from the FXML with `@FXML`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant pane, i will update my question to show it's definition.

Comment: Where is it defined in the controller?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, the pane is not defined in the controller class, 'pane.show(file)' is the action i want to trigger. I'm not too sure what you mean by injecting from the FXML, I used JavaFX scene builder to create my user interface and then created a controller class to handle user interactions.

Comment: I pass my stage object to the controller class.

Comment: You don't need the stage, you just need a reference to the `pane`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject the element from the FXML file into the controller so that you can access it there. See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm) (the section "Add rows to the table", listings 3-14 and 3-16), or the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

Basically, you need to add an `fx:id="..."` attribute to the definition in the FXML file, with a value matching the variable name in the controller class:

```
<Pane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="1.8" style="-fx-border-color: #000000;" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
```

and then annotate the field definition in the controller with `@FXML`. Make sure the variable name matches the `fx:id` value:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable 
{

  @FXML
  private Pane pane ;

  // ...    

  public void openFile()
  { 
    fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(pane.getScene().getWindow());

    if (file != null)
    {
      // display the image in the pane
      pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()));
    }
  }
}
```

In SceneBuilder, you can set the `fx:id` by selecting the `Pane`, and then entering its value under the "Code" section, which is the bottom section in the right pane:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem, although I did make a few minor modifications; Instead of  dynamically creating the ImageView control I hard-coded it. Then I used the file's path to create a new image object and loaded it using the setImage method for the ImageView control.